# Python, dynamically invoke script

Tags: python, command

I want to run a python script from within another. By within I mean any state changes from the child script effect the parent's state. So if a variable is set in the child, it gets changed in the parent.

Normally you could do something like

```
import module
```

But the issue is here the child script being run is an argument to the parent script, I don't think you can use import with a variable

Something like this

```
$python run.py child.py
```

This would be what I would expect to happen

```
#run.py

#insert magic to run argv[1]
print a

#child.py
a = 1

$python run.py child.py
1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) function which allows you to import a module dynamically:

```
module = __import__(sys.argv[1])
```

(You may need to remove the trailing `.py` or not specify it on the command line.)

From the Python documentation:

> Direct use of `__import__()` is rare, except in cases where you want to import a module whose name is only known at runtime.

Comment: thanks greg. bonus points if you can show how to do this if the python file lies in another directory than the script

Comment: @Mike: sure, modify `sys.path`, perhaps like this: `sys.path.append("/your/module/directory")`

Answer (score 3):

While `__import__` certainly executes the specified file, it also stores it in the python modules list. If you want to reexecute the same file, you'd have to do a reload.

You can also take a look at the python [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) statement that could be more suited to your needs.

From Python documentation :

> This statement supports dynamic execution of Python code. The first expression should evaluate to either a string, an open file object, or a code object.

Comment: Python 3 :  [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)